# Error when tried to add hashcode on entity of optaplannercode

Tags: error-handling, drools, equals, hashcode, optaplanner

I practise with a project on optaplanner and I am trying to add equals and hashcode on my entities. First I added the equals method and it worked pretty well! After that I added the hash code and the things went wrong.

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
if (this == o) {
        return true;
    } else if (o instanceof CloudBus) {
        CloudBus otherBus = (CloudBus) o;
        return (capacity == otherBus.getCapacity());
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return new HashCodeBuilder()
            .append(capacity)
            .toHashCode();
}
```

ERROR:
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [WebApp] in context with path [/WebApp] threw exception [Exception executing consequence for rule "conflictingStartBusTooSmall" in com.webapp.jersey: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The constraintMatchTotal (com.webapp.jersey/conflictingStartBusTooSmall=-97hard/0medium/0soft) could not add constraintMatch (com.webapp.jersey/conflictingStartBusTooSmall/[CloudRoute-83435, CloudBus-17]=-1hard/0medium/0soft) to its constraintMatchSet ([com.webapp.jersey/conflictingStartBusTooSmall/[CloudRoute-83555, CloudBus-3]=-22hard/0medium/0soft, com.webapp.jersey/conflictingStartBusTooSmall/[CloudRoute-83580, CloudBus-3]=-4hard/0medium/0soft, com.webapp.jersey/conflictingStartBusTooSmall/[CloudRoute-83594, CloudBus-3]=-8hard/0medium/0soft, com.webapp.jersey/conflictingStartBusTooSmall/[CloudRoute-83753, CloudBus-3]=-1hard/0medium/0soft, com.webapp.jersey/conflictingStartBusTooSmall/[CloudRoute-83479, CloudBus-4]=-6hard/0medium/0soft, com.webapp.jersey/conflictingStartBusTooSmall/[CloudRoute-83435, CloudBus-6]=-1hard/0medium/0soft, com.webapp.jersey/conflictingStartBusTooSmall/[CloudRoute-83429, CloudBus-8]=-26hard/0medium/0soft, com.webapp.jersey/conflictingStartBusTooSmall/[CloudRoute-83610, CloudBus-8]=-17hard/0medium/0soft, com.webapp.jersey/conflictingStartBusTooSmall/[CloudRoute-83403, CloudBus-10]=-11hard/0medium/0soft]).] with root cause

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to include another attribute in CloudBus's `equals()` and `hashCode()` that will make a difference between two distinct CloudBuses with the same capacity. A good candidate is the bus's ID. Since ID is unique there's not much point to include other attributes in `equals()` and `hashCode()` (two distinct buses will be always unequal no matter if they have the same capacity etc).

The problem with comparing only based on the capacity is that two distinct buses can be equal (and have the same hashCode). As a result, you'll have two distinct constraint matches which are equal and so the latter one cannot be added to `ConstraintMatchTotal`'s `constraintMatchSet` because an "equal" constraint match is already in it. See [ConstraintMatchTotal](https://github.com/kiegroup/optaplanner/blob/7.24.0.Final/optaplanner-core/src/main/java/org/optaplanner/core/api/score/constraint/ConstraintMatchTotal.java#L128-L133). This is apparent from the exception message when given a better formatting:

```
ERROR: SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [WebApp] in context with path [/WebApp] threw exception [
Exception executing consequence for rule "conflictingStartBusTooSmall" in com.webapp.jersey: java.lang.IllegalStateException:
  The constraintMatchTotal (com.webapp.jersey/conflictingStartBusTooSmall=-97hard/0medium/0soft)
  could not add constraintMatch (com.webapp.jersey/conflictingStartBusTooSmall/[CloudRoute-83435, CloudBus-17]=-1hard/0medium/0soft)
  to its constraintMatchSet ([
    com.webapp.jersey/conflictingStartBusTooSmall/[CloudRoute-83555, CloudBus-3]=-22hard/0medium/0soft,
    com.webapp.jersey/conflictingStartBusTooSmall/[CloudRoute-83580, CloudBus-3]=-4hard/0medium/0soft,
    com.webapp.jersey/conflictingStartBusTooSmall/[CloudRoute-83594, CloudBus-3]=-8hard/0medium/0soft,
    com.webapp.jersey/conflictingStartBusTooSmall/[CloudRoute-83753, CloudBus-3]=-1hard/0medium/0soft,
    com.webapp.jersey/conflictingStartBusTooSmall/[CloudRoute-83479, CloudBus-4]=-6hard/0medium/0soft,
--> com.webapp.jersey/conflictingStartBusTooSmall/[CloudRoute-83435, CloudBus-6]=-1hard/0medium/0soft,
    com.webapp.jersey/conflictingStartBusTooSmall/[CloudRoute-83429, CloudBus-8]=-26hard/0medium/0soft,
    com.webapp.jersey/conflictingStartBusTooSmall/[CloudRoute-83610, CloudBus-8]=-17hard/0medium/0soft,
    com.webapp.jersey/conflictingStartBusTooSmall/[CloudRoute-83403, CloudBus-10]=-11hard/0medium/0soft
  ]).
] with root cause
```

Assuming all buses have the same capacity, the highlighted constraint match has the same hashCode as the constraint match that is going to be inserted because both have the same CloudRoute and a bus with the same capacity.

Comment: So changing default object equality can't just break Entity Tabu Search (not the default algo, so only a low percentage of users use it), but also the "explaining the score" API (ConstraintMatchTotal / Indictment), which - sooner or later - everyone uses. That's interesting! I suspect the reason why we haven't seen this happen more is because as long as 2 different entities in the same solution aren't considered equal, it's fine.